# how to check the ID of the input data for uniqueness in sctruct?

Tags: c

I have a code with struct. The code reads the keyboard data, but there are several requirements: 1. it must check that the identification number does not repeats and is unique to the user.
2. The entered name should only accept uppercase letters. 
I struggled quite a bit but failed.
This is my structure:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char name[60];
    int ID;
    int license;
    char diploma[15];
    char position[50];
}arhitekt;
typedef struct Node
{
    arhitekt data;
    struct Node* next;
}node;
```

And this is my function for reading data:

```
arhitekt InputArhitekt(node* head)
{
    arhitekt data;
    printf("Name:");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); scanf("%s", &data.name); //here the entered name should only accept uppercase letters
    printf("ID:");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); scanf("%d", &data.ID); //here the identification number does not repeats and is unique to the user
    printf("license:");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); scanf("%d", &data.license);
    printf("diploma:");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); scanf("%s", data.diploma);
    printf("Position:");
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); scanf("%s", data.position);
    return data;
}
```

i will be very grateful if anyone can help

Comment: for the name use `"%59[A-Z]"`

Comment: You seem to be implementing a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), you may want to read up on that. Once you have a working implementation, you can add a condition to the insertion code that will check if the index is already present in the list.